# Custom Plugin w/ Custom Post Types - Custom Posts Are Showing at all Privilege Levels - Is this possible to adjust?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, user-roles

We created a custom plugin.

The custom plugin allows users to post specific post types.

Under each user account, all of these custom post types display under the relative post type.

For example, user Foo logs in and posts A, B and C Articles.

Then, user Bar logs in and can see A, B and C Articles in his Articles post type list.

User FooFoo can also see Articles A, B and C.

These Articles are shared across all users BUT we need the Articles confined only to the specific user they belong to.

Is this possible? Since we are using our own custom plugin and creating these custom posts utilizing the standard WP custom post types?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.  Add the following to either your plugin code or the theme's functions.php file:

```
function mypo_parse_query_useronly( $wp_query ) {
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/edit.php' ) !== false ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
            global $current_user;
            $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->id );
        }
    }
}

add_filter('parse_query', 'mypo_parse_query_useronly' );
```

Reference original source [here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-limit-the-wordpres-posts-screen-to-only-show-authors-their-own-posts/)

This will limit the posts displayed to the each author's own posts only.

Comment: jdm2112, thank you for the suggestion. we've been searching the codex specifically and this suggestion did not come up. will give this a shot and see how it pans out. will post any added tips we come across if we can resolve it.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution will not work in our scenario. I will post details as to the specifics as soon as we find a solution.